# How does Python convert <class 'collections.Counter'> into list?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

```
nums = Counter(nums)
print(list(nums),nums)

#1 
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
[1, 2, 3] Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})

#2 
nums = [3,0,1,0]
[3, 0, 1] Counter({0: 2, 3: 1, 1: 1})
```

How does Python convert a <class 'collections.Counter'> into list. In case of #1 it shows in order of occurrence but in case #2 it shows it in order of some other order.
I have found out that to have it in order of occurrence, most_common() is used.

Comment: It's the same in both: in the order of appearance in the list i.e. if you look at the unique elements in the lists and keep only their first appearances, that's what you'll get. (This is probably guaranteed only for >= 3.7 where `dict`s remember the insertion order.)

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` data type has no order, and after calling each time, you will see a dictionary-type variable whose order is messed up, and this feature increases the speed of search for key, value by 'in'. Therefore, because the output of `Counter` is of `dict` type. The order of the values ​​is not established.